# How can I fix a '[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...' error when running my Node.js application?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run new key value "dev"
but it make error like.

PS D:\webDev\NodeJs\mernbackend> npm run dev

> mernbackend@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon src/app.js

[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/app.js`
node:events:491
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000

Node.js v18.15.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.